# Changing Font and Text Size with WPBakery

Tags: fonts, text

I help to manage a site where the manager does most of the site construction through WPBakery Page Builder. I can't help but notice that when I try to add a block of text, it is locked to a default size, and there are no styling options aside from bolding, italicizing and changing the text color. I would love to have more options like fonts, but I am not sure this is even something that exists in the builder as it stands. I have checked the more standard Wordpress editor, and have not been able to find an option to adjust text size there either, though I could be missing something obvious. I have been given permission to install additional plugins, but I am not even sure where the best place is to look. My questions are, first, whether text styling exists in the base WPBakery editor, and if not, what the best way is to get access to those features.